# How to parse packet buffer into struct

Tags: c++, struct, arduino

I have my answer with netbios information and I think my parsing isn't right, can someone help me to do that right? Thanks a lot.

I receive multiple ips and I want to store them into my struct

Here is my struct:

```
typedef struct PACK({
  uint16_t id;
  uint8_t flags1;
  uint8_t flags2;
  uint16_t qcount;
  uint16_t acount;
  uint16_t nscount;
  uint16_t adcount;
  uint8_t name_len;
  char name[NBNS_MAX_HOSTNAME_LEN + 1];
  uint16_t type;
  uint16_t clas;
  uint32_t ttl;
  uint16_t data_len;
  struct {                <------------ HERE I DID ANOTHER STRUCT FOR MULTIPLE IP (LOOK BELOW)
    uint16_t flags;
    uint32_t addr;
  } addrs[];
}) nbns_answer_t;
```

And here is my packet in wireshark:

[image: Wireshark packet]

Here is my parse:

```cpp
nbns_answer_t* data = (nbns_answer_t*) response;
```

When I do like this I didn't have all ips (or i'm not dealing well with them?):

```
if (!(memcmp(data->name, "FDENEBFCFECNEEEFEDELFDCACACACACA", sizeof(data->name)))) {
        if (data->acount >= 1) {   
          for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(addrs[]); i++) {
            Serial.printf("\n%x", data->addrs[i].addr); <------------------
          }
```

I get this:

```
138
a8c00000
0
0
138
```

Thanks !

Comment: How is `data` allocated/what does it point to?  i.e. have you allocated enough space for `addr` array?

Comment: Why don't you change addrs[] to addrs[4]?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm, I edited to add my parse, is that you wanted ?

Comment: @JaeMannYeh, addrs depends on network adapter active on the PC that answer my query

Comment: Why not use `data_len` to calculate the number of items in `addrs`? 18 is a multiple of 6 (sizeof uint32_t + sizeof uint16_t). `sizeof addrs` will not magically tell you how many items are in that "array".

Comment: What is `sizeof(addrs[])`?

Comment: @JaeMannYeh This is a C trick called "flexible array members" that permits an unknown number of `addr`s. It's technically not valid C++ but hey